# Call function from parent template in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a button in parent component template like below.

```
   <template>
        <div class="data_table">
            <button class="mini ui button" @click="show">                  
        </div>
   </template>
```

This `show()` is kept in child component like below

```
<script>  
    export default {   
        data: 
            function () {
                return {
                    value: this.active1
                }
            },
        props: {
            active1: true
        },        
        methods: {
            show () {
                this.active1 = true
            }
        },  
    }
</script>
```

How can I call that `show()` function ?

I am using `vue-cli`.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean button is a component?

Comment: Thanks @samayo for your reply. No, that button is inside Parent Template along with other HTML content. Thanks

Comment: I think maybe you should add more example

Comment: Thanks @samayo . I added more code, I think that'll be helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: one thing what you can do is, emit the event from child and work the event on parent and pass the value to child using props.

Comment: Thanks @EmJiMadhu for your reply. I am new in Vue.js. Could you please show me some sample ?

Answer (score 0):

**Child Component**

```
<template>
 <div class="data_table">
    <button class="mini ui button" @click="show">                  
 </div>
</template>


data: => ({
 value: this.active1
}),
props: {
 active1: {
   type: Boolean
 }
},
methods: {
  show () {
    this.$emit('someEventName')
  }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
 <template>
    <child-component
       :active1="booleanValue"
       @someEventName="show"
    />
</template>


data: => ({
 booleanValue: false
}),
method: {
 show () {
   this.booleanValue = true
 }
}
```